# Prototype alternative to jQuery's replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I have a small section with some content that is replaced using ajax. However, I am restricted to prototype:

```
function ajaxCartUpdateShippingNotice( productId ) {
    var aj = new Ajax.Request("/hint/block/index?id=" + productId, {
        method: "GET",
        onComplete: function( result ) {
            $( "#delivery--notice" ).replace( result );
        }
    });
};
```

My HTML content is something like this:

```
<div id="delivery--notice">
    <p>Some content here.</p>
</div>
```

and I know with jQuery I can do; is there a way to do this with prototype?

```
$( selector ).replaceWith( html );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight out of [the documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/replace/):

> **`Element.replace`**
>
> `Element.replace(element[, newContent]) → Element`
>
> Replaces `element` *itself* with `newContent` and returns `element`.

As with most things PrototypeJS, it's also available as [a method on elements](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/replace/):

> **`Element#replace`**
>
> `Element#replace([newContent]) → Element`
>
> Replaces `element` *itself* with `newContent` and returns `element`.

Comment: I've tried this:  It doesn't work :S i'll update my question to show how i'm doing it.

Comment: @Ash: Prototype's `$` is *fundamentally different* from jQuery's `$`. It takes an *id*, not a selector. So remove the `#`: `$( "delivery--notice" ).replace( result );` If you're going to be working in Prototype, it's worth stepping back and having a good read through the docs. Prototype is not set-based like jQuery, so using it is quite different.

Comment: This is true, thanks for pointing that out.  I'm not going to be working with prototype that often, nevertheless I didn't even notice the # there.